# Failing to make a SOAP request via SSL with client certificate

Tags: java, ssl, soap, client-certificates

I'm failing to make a successfull SOAP request via SSL with a client certificate. Since I have mutiple outgoing connections with different client certificates I have to handle the keystore programmatically. You find my Java code below.

If I set `-Djavax.net.debug=all` the I found this line in the logs:

```
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
```

So that's pretty obvious, but I don't know why this happens. Any ideas what's wrong or how to debug this?

```
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/path_to_client_certificate.p12");

    Assert.assertNotNull(is);

    ks.load(is, "my_password".toCharArray());
    kmf.init(ks, "my_password".toCharArray());
    sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

    URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/path_to_local_wsdl_file.wsdl");
    BillingService billingService = new BillingService(url);
    BoBillingService boBillingService = billingService.getWsHttp();

    BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) boBillingService;
    bindingProvider.getRequestContext()
            .put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
                    "https://www.hostname.com/service_path");

    ExecutePingOut executePingOut = boBillingService.executePing("My Text", true);

    LOGGER.trace(executePingOut.getMessage().getValue());
```

Running this code gives the following output:

```
---[HTTP request - https://www.hostname.com/service_path]---
Accept: text/xml, multipart/related
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "https://www.hostname.com/service_path/ExecutePing"
User-Agent: JAX-WS RI 2.2.8 svn-revision#13980
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
    <ExecutePing xmlns="https://www.hostname.com/service_path" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EBS.BO.Billing">
    <text>My Text</text>
    <exceptionTest>true</exceptionTest>
</ExecutePing>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>--------------------


---[HTTP response - https://www.hostname.com/service_path - 500]---
null: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Connection: close
Content-Length: 311
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 18 Mar 2016 05:31:31 GMT
Server: Apache (proxied)
Set-Cookie: ittrksessid=6d564320.52e4c0f3a5ec0; path=/; domain=.hostname.ch
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
        <faultcode xmlns:a="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">a:FailedAuthentication</faultcode>
        <faultstring xml:lang="de-CH">Access is denied.</faultstring>
    </s:Fault>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

from Java 1.8u51+, 1.7.0_85+ and 1.6.0_101+ Oracle changed security policy for SSL certificates

i have same problem
trying this:
i use 1st and 2nd classes from [here](https://alesaudate.wordpress.com/2010/08/09/how-to-dynamically-select-a-certificate-alias-when-invoking-web-services/)
HostnameVerifier class from ASIX as

```
    HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return fias.HostnameVerifier.DEFAULT.verify(hostname, session);
        }
    };
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    con.connect();
```

and classes from [here](https://gist.github.com/kdelfour/b2a449a1bac23e3baec8) for send SOAP
make your own keyStore and trustStore
i make connecting by IP and i use aliases for keys (they equal in stores)
it works for me
PS: [my other simple method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37414367/simple-soap-client-ssl-connection-error) does not work for SOAP yet ((